# Two elements side by side in outer div, one left sided, one right sided

Tags: html, css

I know there were many similar questions, but I couldn't figure it out.

I have the following div:

```css
#inputHeader {
  width: 100%;
  background: #30273a;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#inputHeaderTitle {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#inputHeaderEdit {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputHeader">
  <p id="inputHeaderTitle">Header</p>
  <span id="inputHeaderEdit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</div>
```

I want the "inputHeaderTitle" on the left side of the div, and the "inputHeaderEdit"-span on the right side. How can I do this?

**Edit:**

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9nuhay76/1 where I did float:left/right. But if I do so, the outer DIV gets a height of 0px. Why?

Comment: Float one left and the other right?

Comment: Float's should not be used for positioning you are in the right place with inline-block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#inputHeader {
  width: 100%;
  background: #30273a;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#inputHeaderTitle {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1;
}
#inputHeaderEdit {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputHeader">
  <p id="inputHeaderTitle">Header</p>
  <span id="inputHeaderEdit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Edit</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @progNewbie although this will work you have to remember that this isn't really supported on IE.

Comment: @DCdaz , flexbox works in IE10 and up. but need proper prefixes... You can get prefixes from [https://autoprefixer.github.io/](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Comment: Thats far from true. There is a large amount of bugs present on it with or without the vendor prefix. The fact that it needs a vendor prefix for a recent version of IE should be ringing all sorts of alarm bells.

Comment: The issue in the question can be fixed by adding `overflow:hidden;` inside `#inputHeader` [https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/9nuhay76/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/9nuhay76/6/) .... I suggested flexbox since it provides more options.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="inputHeader">
 <p id="inputHeaderTitle" style="float:left">Header</p>
 <span id="inputHeaderEdit" style="float:right" class="glyphicon glyphicon- pencil"></span>
</div>
```

Do you mean like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add float: right
Like this:

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wedivobequ/2/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should not use float for positioning. You are in the right place with display inline-block.

try using display table instead though and then text alignment to position them left or right as bellow.

```css
#inputHeader {
  width: 100%;
  background: #30273a;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#inputHeaderTitle {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#inputHeaderEdit {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* NEW */

.align-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.t-align {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.align-left {
  text-align: left;
}
.align-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputHeader" class="align-table">
  <div class="t-align">
    <p id="inputHeaderTitle">Header</p>
  </div>
  <div class="t-align align-right">
    <span id="inputHeaderEdit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```